# Is it possible to nest quantum Markov chain Monte Carlo, mean and minimum algorithms?

Tags: grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification, quantum-walks

Montanaro A. 2015 [Quantum speedup of Monte Carlo methods](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.2015.0301) makes the following claim of an algorithm to estimate the mean output $\mu$ of an arbitrary algorithm A, with near-quadratic speedup over classical methods:

> An  important  aspect  of  this  construction  is  that  the
> underlying  subroutine need  not  be a  classical  randomized
> procedure,  but  can  itself  be  a  quantum  algorithm.  This
> enables  any quantum  speedup  obtained  by A to  be  used  within  the
> overall  framework  of  the  algorithm

So, a few questions relating to nesting quantum algorithms in this way:

1. Does this statement also hold for previous algorithms of this type such as Brassard's algorithm for computing the mean of A?
2. Does this statement hold for Grover search and hence quantum computation of minimum also?
3. Does this statement hold for the quadratic quantum improvements on Markov chain Monte Carlo algorithms presented later in the Montanaro paper?